# Get a path in a TextField from an event

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I would like to choose a file in my app and then write its path in a Textfield and use it as a Variable for my main app. 
I did my interface and add a few things like when I press a button I choose a file but I don't know how to get that path.
Here is my main app code :

```
package ch.makery.adress;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;


public class MainApp extends Application {



    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("PersonOverview.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
        stage.setTitle("Appication Extraction et remplissage Excel");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();    
}
}
```

And here my controller class :

```
package ch.makery.adress;

import java.awt.FileDialog;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class HexaController implements Initializable {
       static JFrame fileDialog;
        @FXML
        private ComboBox<String> hexa;
        ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


        @FXML
        private void dar(ActionEvent event){
            FileDialog fd1=new FileDialog(fileDialog,"Choisissez un fichier d'entree",FileDialog.LOAD);
            fd1.setDirectory("C:\\");
            fd1.setVisible(true);
            String filename1=fd1.getFile();
            String Directory1=fd1.getDirectory();
            String path1=Directory1 + filename1;
        }

        @FXML
        private void modele(ActionEvent event){
            JFrame parentFrame=new JFrame();
             FileDialog filechooser = new FileDialog (parentFrame, "Choisir un modèle Excel à copier",FileDialog.LOAD);
             filechooser.setDirectory("C:\\");
             filechooser.setVisible(true);
             String directory_copy = filechooser.getDirectory();
             String name_copy= filechooser.getFile();
             String path_copy = (directory_copy+name_copy);
        }

        @FXML
        private void sortie (ActionEvent event){
            JFrame parentFrame2=new JFrame();
             FileDialog filechooser2 = new FileDialog (parentFrame2, "Choisir une destination d'enregistrement",FileDialog.SAVE);
             filechooser2.setDirectory("C:\\");
             filechooser2.setVisible(true);
             String directory_save = filechooser2.getDirectory();
             String name_save= filechooser2.getFile();
             String path_save = (directory_save+name_save+".xls");
        }
        @FXML
        private void annuler (ActionEvent event){
            System.exit(0);
        }


        @FXML
        private ComboBox<Integer>methode;
        ObservableList<Integer>nombre = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        @FXML
        private TextField entree;

        @FXML
        private TextField excel;

        @FXML
        private TextField sortie;


public HexaController(){

}

public void initialize(URL url,ResourceBundle rb){

    list.add(new String("OUI"));
    list.add(new String("NON"));
    hexa.setItems(list);
    nombre.add(new Integer(1));
    nombre.add(new Integer(2));
    nombre.add(new Integer(3));
    nombre.add(new Integer(4));
    nombre.add(new Integer(5));
    methode.setItems(nombre);
}
}
```

What should I do next to make it work ? Don't know where to start.
Thanks

Comment: in the lines : `String directory_save = filechooser2.getDirectory();
             String name_save= filechooser2.getFile(); ` , arent you getting the  full file path? you could take that and update the corresponding text field you want or pass it in a global variable

Comment: On that one it's a file that a Save. So I just put the path and the name of the file.

Comment: How could I update it into the textfiled or a golbal variable ? That actualy what I don't know.

Comment: ok posting it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as it is a JavaFX application , i suppose that you will start an app per user so you wont have issues with global information shared in the memory.

i) the first approach is to have a private String latestFilePath , for your example , in your HexaController and when the user does a file opening , you could take the filePath and pass it on the String field

```
String directory_save = filechooser2.getDirectory(); 
String name_save= filechooser2.getFile();
this.latestFilePath = directory_save+name_save;
```

So later you can use it anywhere you want , with a simple if statement to check whether it is null

ii) as a second approach , which can be an extension of the above , you could simply take the filePath and set it on your text field

```
 String filename1=fd1.getFile();
 String Directory1=fd1.getDirectory();
 String path1=Directory1 + filename1;
 entree.setText(path1);
```

Comment: It works very well ! Thanks I thought that it was not possible to do it as simply as it.